# Неработоспособный window.onload

Tags: javascript, php, html, отладка

Имеется следующий каркас приложения:

```
// Check if the browser has support for the Geolocation API
alert(5);

if (!navigator.geolocation) 
    {
       alert("No support browser");    
    } 
    else 
    {
      alert("Working");
      window.onload=function () 
      {
        alert("Inside in locinit");
      }; 

    }
```

При выполнении на экран выводится сначала 5, далее Working, затем по идее должно вывестись Inside in locinit, но нет - оно не выводит на экран ожидаемую строку, т.е. внутрь `window.onload` не выполнился. Подскажите как исправить ошибку.

Данный скрипт я подключаю к странице с помощью

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/geocode1.js"></script>
```

в

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Electromart</title>
    <!-- <link href="//db.onlinewebfonts.com/c/8274996f8cf973b15814827fa281e485?family=TechnojunkW00-Regular" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/eshop.css">
    <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/geoloc.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/geocode1.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Как вы подключаете этот скрипт к странице?

Comment: @andreymal с помощью тега скрипт в хэде